# Can't install any GoLang script in Linux

Tags: go

When I try to run any Go script it show me this error

I installed go lang step by step from this link

https://www.tecmint.com/install-go-in-linux/

When I setup go script like this

```
go get github.com/tomnomnom/waybackurls
```

I got error like this

> github.com/tomnomnom/waybackurls
>   src/github.com/tomnomnom/waybackurls/main.go:191: u.Hostname undefined
>   (type *url.URL has no field or method Hostname)

Answer (score -1):

If you are following the guide you linked by copy-pasting commands, you will have installed Go 1.7.3. The function `url.Hostname()` was added in Go 1.8.

I suggest completely ignoring that guide. Remove `/usr/local/go`, remove `~/go_projects` and undo the path related stuff.

Instead, use the package manager of your OS to install Go.

Most likely, this means you should do either `sudo apt install golang` (for Ubuntu, Debian, ...) or `sudo dnf install golang` (Fedora, CentOS, ...).

That will give you the latest version that is supported by distro maintainer (which at the moment is probably 1.11 or 1.12, depending on your distro).

As an alternative to the packagemanager, download the latest version from https://golang.org/dl/.

This approach also gives you an installation that follows the Go ecosystem their conventions for paths (I'm not sure if `~/go_projects` was ever a think, but it isn't today).

Comment: Installing from golang.org is the better option, as it will give the latest version.

Comment: @Adrian Sure, it gives you what is now the latest version. And then in 3 years, you're still on that version, because nobody bothered updating (unless they're a professional sysadmin, but those don't open SO questions about things like this) including whatever security issues have been found in the mean time. So in principal I agree downloading the latest version is better, in practice I think its not the best advice in this kind of situation.

Comment: You're assuming a non-sysadmin is more likely to run `dnf update` on a regular basis? I'm not sure, and even if they did, that won't give them the latest anyway - e.g. fedora 29 repo offers Go 1.11.12, when the latest is 1.12.9, and the latest 1.11.x is 1.11.13.